# Unexpected behaviour calling form functions (destroy close) FMX (Delphi XE5) Mobile

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing an app for FireMonkey XE5 Mobile (Nexus4). The calling of the form procedures are showing unpexpected behaviour:

When the App is closed using the active app menu on the mobile phone (so not using the app itself), none of the form functions are called. However when starting the app again the following calls are done:

1. Create
2. Destroy
3. Show
4. Activate

Where obviously the destroy procedure frees the objects that are created during the create procedure.

Also when using the 'Back' button on the Nexus4 to close the app, the close function is called twice and doesn't close the app. But it does close when the procedure is not implemented. 
Of course I can finish the app myself, but that shouldn't be necessary.

How to deal with this issues?